# How to consume a postgresql database from a net core api

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core

Hello I want to connect my web API to a postgresql database but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Npgsql EF Core provider, you could following below steps:

1.add a dependency on `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` with correct version.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2.Set your own connection string in appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DbConnection": "User ID =postgres;Password=123456;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MyTestdatabase;Integrated Security = True; Pooling=true"
},
```

3.In startup.cs ,register the dbContext with

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt => 
            opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));
```

Or refer to http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/